# modelのインスタンスの配列をソートする方法

Tags: ruby-on-rails

ArticleとUserというモデルがあります。

```
 class Article < ApplicationRecord
   belongs_to :user
 end

 class User < ApplicationRecord
   has_many :articles
 end
```

Userのidをキーとして、Aritcleをグループ化しました。

```
 Article.includes(:user).references(:user)
        .group_by{|a| a.user_id}
```

この結果は以下のようにUserのidがキー、Articleモデルのインスンタンスの配列がバリューとなったハッシュが返ってくると思います。

```
{ 1 => [...], 2=> [...], 3=> [...], ..}
```

このArticleモデルのインスタンスを**各配列内で**ソートするにはどうしたらいいでしょうか。

Answer (score 0):

Hash上になったあとであれば `Hash#transform_values` のブロックでソートすればよさそうです。

元々Rails(ActiveSupport)で実装されたメソッドですが、Ruby 2.4.xにも採用され、ネイティブ実装されています。

https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12512
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/Hash.html#method-i-transform_values

また、 `group_by` はレコードを読み込んだ後のRuby上の処理であり、その[実装](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/trunk/enum.c#L863)上、元データの出現順に並びますから、 ARel(=SQL)レベルで `order` しておくだけでもよさそうです。